# Extracting the contents of a tar folder into a target directory

Tags: linux, backup, tar, data-recovery

I have a tar archive and I need to extract the contents of a directory into another directory.

So for example the content may be located in `/home/me/stuff/` and everything in the `stuff` folder should be extracted to `/extract`.  So after the extract is complete everything that was in the archived `/home/me/stuff/` folder is now in the `/extract` folder.

Thoughts?

Comment: You are not telling us how and in which directory you generated that tar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, it looks like, with GNU tar, the following will do it:

```
tar --extract --file in.tar --directory /extract /home/me/stuff --strip 3
```

Simulating with an archive that has the following contents:

```
$ tar tf in.tar
home/
home/me/
home/me/stuff/
home/me/stuff/b
home/me/stuff/a
home/foo
```

And an output directory `/tmp/extract` (which must be created beforehand), we get:

```
$ find /tmp/extract
/tmp/extract
/tmp/extract/b
/tmp/extract/a
```

Note how the file `foo` was not extracted at all.

Comment: Ah, and now I see that you probably meant for the leading part `home/me/stuff` to be stripped. Oops.

Comment: With GNU tar, there's `--strip-components`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up noticing that right after posting my answer.

Comment: OK - So IIUC the --strip 3 means skip everything starting from root (/) down three directories?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Perhaps it's not very convenient to have to compute the value `3`, but then again it's possible to write a script around this if this is a recurring need.

Comment: it seems you are old in StackExchange.you should know a good answer is which has explain of solution.